TIFF Raster to a Geodatabase
I have downloaded a bare earth DEM which is stored as a TIFF file.
I am trying to add my DEM to a geodatabase (using raster to geodatabase tool) but I am receiving the error message :
Failed to convert DEMNAME.tif.  ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Contact Esri Technical Support (http://esriurl.com/support) to Report a Bug, and refer to the error help for potential solutions or workarounds.
Failed to execute (CopyRaster).
I have also tried to convert my TIFF raster to another format using the raster to other format tool and have received the same error.
Any suggestions or work arounds? Or is there something I am doing incorrectly?

EDITS: 
Input:
Raster: TIFF DEM (downloaded from here : https://geodata.wisc.edu/catalog/5fdfc925-96ed-474d-9cc2-0de096e03135)
It was unzipped and is displayed correctly on the ArcMap.
Geodatabase : Normal geodatabase that I was able to upload other rasters to.  I am using the most updated version of ArcGIS Pro

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. 999999 is a generic error. You need to [Edit] the Question to provide details of what parameters you entered.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It is difficult to provide specific advice without more information about your input, but have you checked that the data downloaded ok? Can you open it and view it in GIS software?

Just took the tour! I'm confused on what you mean by inputs. My input was my TIF raster and the geodatabase I created? I did not change the environments or anything fancy. I can view the DEM in GIS. Here is the link to my data: https://geodata.wisc.edu/catalog/5fdfc925-96ed-474d-9cc2-0de096e03135 I am confused on why it isn't working as I have uploaded TIFFs to geodatabases before. The data is unzipped, looks normal in the metadata and everything.
